# print files name with "for" loop

Tags: jquery

I would like to create a "for" loop that print the name of the files I upload.

I don't know how many files it will be so I'm using loop.

I know that i did something wrong. can you tell me what?

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field multi' maxlength='2' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif"  id="uploadFile0"/>
<button class="btn btn-primary submit" >SEND</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('submit','form',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the standard form submission, as you're using 

    var $form = $(this);
    var act = 'add';

alert ($form.find('.file-field').length);

for (var i = 0; i <= $form.find('.file-field').length; i++) {
    alert ($form.find('.file-field')[i].name );
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f69tc7xj/2/)

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    var file = $('#file')[0].files;
    for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        console.log(file[i].name);
        console.log(file[i].size);
        console.log(file[i].type);
    }
});
```

You can try the way i get the data in this for loop